# Unreal Engine 5 SDK not setup packaging error

Tags: sdk, packaging

So, i tried packaging my first game in unreal engine, and it wont work.

I wanted to package it for windows, and this error message comes:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwaNn.png)

i tried everything, copied hostfxr.dll, downloaded 7 sdks and dotnet cores and it doesn't work.
btw this is the console log:

UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): Running AutomationTool...
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): set DOTNET_ROOT=%UE_DOTNET_DIR%
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): rem Disables use of any installed version of dotnet
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): set DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP=0
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): rem for dotnet applications that require older dotnet runtimes, this will allow them to use our bundled dotnet runtime
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): set DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD=LatestMajor
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): rem skip dotnet verification when using our submitted sdk as we know it is up to date
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): ECHO Using bundled DotNet SDK version: %UE_DOTNET_VERSION%
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): goto Succeeded
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows): exit /B 0

how can i fix it?